# Re-read a file from start after the program finishes reading it python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which I am reading in python. The code is something along these lines:

```
with open("total.csv", 'rb') as input1:
    reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        # Read the CSV row by row.
```

Actually this file contains numerous URLs that I wish to check for updates and I want my program to start from the beginning of the file once I complete the list. If I want to stop it I will manually kill the process. However, I don't know what should I do after reading the last row so that the program should start from the beginning of the file. I want to keep on reading the file in a loop so that the file is read unless I manually terminate the process running my script. Can anyone tell how do I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File objects have a `seek()` method; use that to seek to 0. But make sure to `time.sleep()` for a short file before reading thd file or your program will saturate a CPU core and disk IO.

Or better yet, just re-enter the `with` block to open the file afresh.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how do I implement in program. Say in my code I do this:

<code> with open("total.csv", 'rb') as input1:
    reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        # Read the CSV row by row.
    input1.seek(0) 
    time.sleep(3) </code>

but now how do I go to the beginning of the `for` loop as it has already terminated.

Comment: have you ever heard of loops?