# How do I go to the first record of a CSV file within the same "for" loop?

Tags: python, csv

I had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159053/re-read-a-file-from-start-after-the-program-finishes-reading-it-python/23159107) and the answer that I get was to use the `seek()` method. Now I am doing the following:

```
with open("total.csv", 'rb') as input1:
    time.sleep(3)
    input1.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
       #Read the CSV row by row.
```

However, I want to navigate to the first record of the CSV **within the same for loop**. I know that my loop won't terminate that ways but that's precisely what I want. I don't want the `for` loop to end and if it reaches the last record I want to navigate back to the first record and read the whole file all over again (and keep reading it). How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to call `input1.seek(0)` inside the loop?

Comment: if the file isn't too large, use `itertools.cycle` to repeat the whole list again and again.

Comment: @Bakuriu Ya, I did. It then just keeps on reading the first row.

Comment: @Daniel - Na, the file is pretty large.

Comment: Ah, so you just want to read the **whole** file again and again. I thought you had an `if something: repeat_file_read` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, create an generator:

```
def repeated_reader(input, reader):
    while True:
        input.seek(0)
        for row in reader:
            yield row

with open("total.csv", 'rb') as input1:
    reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter="\t")
    for row in repeated_reader(input1, reader):
        #Read the CSV row by row.
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be in the `for`-loop? You could achieve this behaviour like this (untested):

```
with open("total.csv", 'rb') as input1:
    time.sleep(3)
    reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter="\t")
    while True:
        input1.seek(0)
        for row in reader:
            #Read the CSV row by row.
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually calculated the total number of rows in the CSV and when I was on the last row I did `input1.seek(0)`

```
row_count = sum(1 for row in csv.reader(open('total.csv')))
print row_count


row_count2 = 0

with open("total.csv", 'rb') as input1:
        time.sleep(3)
        input1.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter="\t") 
        for row in reader:
            count += 1
            #Read the CSV row by row.
            if row_count2 == row_count:
                row_count2 = 0
                time.sleep(3)
                input1.seek(0)
```

Comment: Both the other answers are better than this one.

Comment: Actually, for each row in the file, I made a URL (from the data in the row) and opened the URL in a web browser using Selenium. Using the `while True` method opened up as many browsers as it could and hogged up memory. Plus, if you are writing to some common file while doing this, the common fil was being overwritten in a weird way. That's why I specifically wanted the to go to the beginning of the file *inside* the `for` loop.

Comment: Then the issue is with how you launch Selenium, right?

Comment: Might be. However, I am not entirely sure of that.